# Define a single background with beamer in LaTex

Tags: background, latex, beamer

I am using the Singapore theme in Beamer for multiple reasons (this theme is kind of clean, without too much vertical/horizontal bar everywhere, progress dots, ...) and so, I would like to keep it.

Anyway, I defined a back ground with tikz with a circular color gradient background for slide content. But, the header is defined with a background too and I can't suceed to remove its background (even after 2 hours in internet lol).

Here is a mwe where you can see the difference between the two background which make an horizontal white line that I do not want.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [outer color = blue!5, inner color = blue!1]
      (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I do to make the background with a circular color gradient for the fullsize of the slide ? Without interruption of the header ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Singapore` theme without the colour gradient boils down to the following settings:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\usetheme{Singapore}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\beamertemplatedotitem


\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [outer color = blue!5, inner color = blue!1]
      (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking !

Answer (score 0):

With the beamer [development version from github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e4f8639f03102ef5f8a75e93d64869d2ee3648e9) or beamer v3.70 (or newer), you can change the colour of the headline gradient to blend in with your background:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=blue!5}

\begin{document}
\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [outer color = blue!5, inner color = blue!1]
      (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\section{Section}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]   
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]